# Do I need to reset() after arsort()?

Tags: php, arrays

Do I need to `reset($array);` after I `arsort($array);` or is the pointer automatically reset after a sort?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: If you are not sure, you should always code defensively. In this case call reset(...)

Comment: I want to be sure of the "official" answer, as otherwise it might change between PHP versions (if I just test it.) I do code defensively, but I thought it might be a waste of CPU cycles (a nanosecond maybe, but it all counts!)

Comment: @Alasdair: only PHP devs can give you an "official" answer

Comment: Well I thought the answer might have been stated somewhere official, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Officially stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152715/do-i-need-to-reset-after-arsort/8153080#8153080)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to call the `reset` function after `asort`, it resets the array as well.

It's officially expressed inside PHP sourcecode which is [publicly available](http://lxr.php.net/), look especially for:

```
ht->pInternalPointer = ht->pListHead;
```

Points to start:

- reset: http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#880
- asort: http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c#508

Answer (score 4):

It's automatically reset, see this [codepad](http://codepad.org/fWn700if) for a live test case